# Conditions on a linear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $x:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be solutions to an $n\times n$ system of linear ODEs. That is,
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x+b(t) \mbox{ and } \frac{dy}{dt}=A(t)y+b(t) \mbox{ for } 0<t<T.$$
The solutions are assumed to be continuous on $[0,T]$ and differentiable on $(0,T)$.

I managed to show that if $A:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is bounded, say
$$\|A(t)v\|\le K\|v\| \mbox{ for } 0\le t\le T \mbox{ and } v\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
then
$$\|x(t)-y(t)\|\le e^{Kt}\|x(0)-y(0)\|.$$

However, I am not sure what can be deduced if $A$ is not only bounded, but also satisfies
$$v^TA(t)v\le-K\|v\|^2\mbox{ for } 0\le t\le T \mbox{ and } v\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining $z(t):=x(t)-y(t)$ the problem is equivalent to show that
$$||z(t)||\leq e^{Kt}||z(0)||$$
for the system $\dot{z}=A(t)z$. Let us first consider the positive definite function $V(t):=z^Tz=||z||^2$ which gives a measure of distance of the system trajectories from the origin. Observe that
$$\dot{V}=\dot{z}^Tz+z^T\dot{z}\Rightarrow|\dot{V}|\leq2||z||.||\frac{dz}{dt}||$$
Besides,
$$|\dot{V}|=|2||z||.\frac{d||z||}{dt}|$$
Comparing the obtained expressions gives
$$|\frac{d||z||}{dt}|\leq||\frac{dz}{dt}||=||A(t)z||$$
$$\Rightarrow |\frac{d||z||}{dt}|\leq K||z||$$
Therefor
$$-K||z||\leq\frac{d||z||}{dt}\leq K||z||$$
Now, using the differential form of the *Gronwall's inequality* (see for example, http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387985138) yields;
$$e^{-Kt}||z(0)||\leq ||z(t)||\leq e^{Kt}||z(0)||$$
**Part 2:** If matrix $A$ satisfies
$$\dot{z}Az\leq –K||z||^2$$
Then,
$$\dot{V}=z^T(A+A^T)z\leq -2K||z||^2$$
Therefore, $V$ is a Lyapunov function for the system which also, satisfies the exponentially stability theorem conditions (see the above book). This means that $\dot{z}=A(t)z$ is exponentially stable and the rate of convergence can be derived as follows.
$$\dot{V}\leq -2KV\ \Rightarrow\ \frac{\dot{V}}{2\sqrt{V}}\leq –K\sqrt{V}$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \frac{d\sqrt{V}}{dt}\leq-K\sqrt{V}$$
Once more, using Gronwall's inequality gives:
$$\sqrt{V(t)}\leq e^{-Kt}\sqrt{V(0)}$$
$$||z(t)||\leq e^{-Kt}||z(0)||$$

Comment: That is what I got for the first part as well, however my question was not about that. Rather, what can be deduced if the following condition is ALSO placed on $A(t)$: $$v^TA(t)v\le-K\|v\|^2\mbox{ for } 0\le t\le T \mbox{ and } v\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Comment: This inequality can be used to show the exponential stability of your system. I updated the answer.